# bootstrap 3 - Restricting some section and js to load on mobile version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How can i restrict some section and js to load in mobile version in bootstrap 3.

For client Engagement i  am using chat and click to call features on a website.
I want to restrict these features loading in mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's Bootstrap can't be used to restrict the load of content or javascript code. Bootstrap load all and only will hide or resize some elements based on screen width (css media queries).

To hide html, see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

You could use [enquire.js](http://wickynilliams.github.com/enquire.js/) to prevent js code to load based on media queries, see for an example: http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/examples/defer-setup/